# Description of Network set up / Admin/Standard user

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu and I am learning to install Ubuntu 14.0.

1. How do you describe network set up?
2. How to set up an administrator and standard user?

Comment: Is [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkAdmin) you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks vembutech, but what about setting up an administrator and standard user? How do I set up either one of them?

Comment: @vembutech Convert your comment to an answer so [Java21][1] can accept it as valid...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As [vembutech](https://askubuntu.com/users/335147/vembutech) already answered Number 1, here's number 2:

The first user being created during install *is* an admin user and you can use that one to log into, go to the dash (the upper-left icon on your screen) and type "user" there.  You will see an icon "User accounts".  Click it and use that screen to define a standard user by pressing on the little <kbd>+</kbd> in the lower left corner. (everything from there on should be straightforward)

As you're new to Ask Ubuntu: Don't thank anyone on this site, but accept their answer as valid if it helped you...  That is the best way of thinking people as their reputation will go up!  ;-)